# Get Directory listing from and FTP Folder from a Portable Class Library Project

Tags: c#, android, ftp, mvvmcross

I'am creating an Android app using Xamarin with the MVVMCross Framework.

Inside my PCL(portable class library),I want to implement an FTP Client Class where I can read files from a specific FTP Folder in an FTP Server hosted in IIS and based on some business rules, to download the files one by one. The download part might not be an issue since I can use the WebRequest and WebResponse classes of the System.Net namespace.

My main issue is that I want to find a way to read the files from the FTP Folder. I cannot use Directory.GetFiles method since it is not supported by the System.IO in PCL, for cross platform compatibility reasons.

I also want to avoid creating my FTPClient class inside my droidUI (GUI) project (where I have access to all the classes of the Framework) because then I will ruin my MVVM multi-layer architecture.

I hope the above makes some sense to what i'am trying to say.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great n+1 video showing how to do [platform specific code](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=yduxdUCKU1c). Using this you would create an interface, that your VM's would use, and you would just create platform specific code.

You might want to consider creating it as a plugin, then others could benefit from it.

This is the best choice if you can't find any cross platform ftp code.